# Troubleshooting developing Portra 800

Tags: film, color, 35mm, developing, kodak

I just performed a shoot with a single roll of Portra 800, new from amazon, in date.

Developed using correct times with replenished fuji C-41 chemistry in a jobo 1500 tank.

I metered the film at ISO 640, spot metering for the face.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/0b5rAXT.png]

Digital shot context, same ISO setting, same shooting method.

Here's some negatives from the first 'test' part of the roll.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/5oUyXZT.png]
Negative 1 (completely unaltered)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/94a35TQ.png]
Negative 1 (auto colour corrected)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/lGdkEVJ.png]
Negative 2 (completely unaltered)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/fckkJSH.png]
Negative 2 (Auto color corrected)

I literally just mixed new batches of developer, bleach and fixer with the correct quantities of replenisher and starter as per usual.

What on earth is happening here?? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: What were the temperatures of your chemicals during each step?

Comment: They look very underdeveloped to me, if you shot at EI 640. (By the way, film has only one correct ISO - the manufacturer discloses it, and it is based on laboratory testing - and shooting it at any other speed involves using an EI, or exposure index.  Most films are sold as their ISO speed, but exceptions are Ilford Delta 3200 and T-Max P3200 which are roughly ISO 1000 (indicated in their instructions).

Comment: How are these negatives?